# Autosize grid columns with repeat(autofit) while also having grid cells span 2 or more columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to create a responsive layout with CSS grid, with grid child elements of variable size. To make the grid responsive, I figured I'd use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-size, 1fr));`

However, if I combine that with `grid-column: span 2;` the grid never collapses to just one column, but instead keeps a minimum of two columns as dictated by the above line.

Here's a mockup of my current code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
}

.grid-item.tall {
  padding: unset;
  border: unset;
}

.grid-item.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Regular grid child</div>
  <div class="grid-item tall">
    <div class="grid-item">Short grid child</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Short grid child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item wide">Wide grid child</div>
 </div>
```

Instead of resizing the columns when the viewport is less than 1000px, the right-hand column is just squished / pushed out of the viewport instead.

How can I achieve a responsive grid layout with cells of variable width / height? The final design will incorporate many more cells, making it cumbersome to size the grid based on media queries, and I'd like not to use Javascript for something like this.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: you want that under 1000px you will have one column?

Answer (score 0):

does this is what you asked?

I added something called media query, it is used to apply CSS styled to specific screen sizes, so here we want to target the width parameter of 1000px if I understood correct, to apply a span of 1 and 1fr.

maybe can add a screenshot with the desired behavior over the current one to make it clear

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
}

.grid-item.tall {
  padding: unset;
  border: unset;
}

.grid-item.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

/* Media query for screens smaller than 1000px */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* This makes the grid have only one column */
  }

  .grid-item.wide {
    grid-column: span 1; /* Override the span for 'wide' items to take only one column */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Regular grid child</div>
  <div class="grid-item tall">
    <div class="grid-item">Short grid child</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Short grid child</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item wide">Wide grid child</div>
 </div>
```